# how to change less property by using different param?

Tags: css, less

I often use similarity less , for example:

```
.position{
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:20px;
}
```

So I want to use a `mixin` :

```
.position(@absolute:absolute;@top:0;@right:0;@bottom:0;@left:0){
    position: @absolute;
    top:@top;
    right: @right;
    bottom:@bottom;
    left:@left;
}
```

But sometimes I don't need `right`， but the function always inject `right` into my code.

So what I should do if I want to have the follow code:

```
.position(@absolute:absolute;@top:12px;@left:12px;@bottom:12px);
//without 'right'
.position{
    position: absolute;
    top:12px;
    bottom:12px;
    left:12px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your mixin like this (it doesn't have any required parameters):

```
.position(
  @position: absolute;
  @top: false;
  @right: false;
  @bottom: false;
  @left: false
){
  position: @position;

  & when not (@top = false) {
    top: @top;
  }

  & when not (@right = false) {
    right: @right;
  }

  & when not (@bottom = false) {
    bottom: @bottom;
  }

  & when not (@left = false) {
    left: @left;
  }
}
```

Now you can set only those params you really need:

```
a {
  .position(
    @top: 20px, 
    @left: 0px
  );
}

b {
  .position(
    @bottom: -50px, 
    @right: 0
  );
}
```

Css output:

```
a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
}
b {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
}
```

Comment: wow,thank for your answer! in fact I don't study LESS well, your code perform fine after i try!